# How to edit json file with data and save it

Tags: java, android, json, file

I have a json file with a lot of objects. This file is located in res/raw. Im reading this file and showing objects in list in my UI. And after user closing activity with this list, changes that user made most be saved in file that was read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is located inside of your apk file, you cannot change it. Instead of that have a flag stored in persistent store. If it is a first run of your application, then read this json file from apk, process it and store it in the device filesystem.

And every next run, check the flag, if it is not the first run, read the file from the filesystem and process it further.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bad way of making things static, but if too urgent for you, you can read json file once and convert it to java model(pojo) object and make that object static, When next time you visit same activity load ui from that static object instead of reading and parsing it again, for safety you can check if pojo class object is null.